# 2002 Honda Civic (Automatic) Intermittent shifting Issue

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, civic, shifting

I have a 2002 Honda Civic that has started having troubles shifiting from park into reverse/drive. It stays in park just fine.

It started where it would shift into reverse and drive just fine, but then when you would accelerate the first time, the car would make noise like it was accelerating but it wouldn't actually move like it was accelerting (it was at the very least moving forward.)

Today, I went to drive it and the car acted like it was in neutral, and would only roll downhill. It did seem like when it was on flat ground it had a tendency to roll forward, whether it was in neutral or drive. I shut it off to do some research, then turned it back on and let it get to running temperature before checking the ATF. That checked out fine. I jumped back in the car and put it into reverse and it worked perfectly.

Any ideas where to go from here? I am fearing the worst(transmission is going) but wanted to crowdsource some other ideas of what it could be. I have a very small amount of knowledge on cars but can always follow directions or youtube videos.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if you've got worn out bushings which are not causing the transmission to actually get put into gear. You could try and put it into "2" or "L" (or however they are marked) instead of drive and see if it shifts into gear.

Comment: I did try all options to see what it would shift into, and when it was acting up there was no difference no matter what gear I went into. Oddly I did nothing besides turn it off and let it sit for a few minutes and then it went into reverse just fine. I just don't see that being the case long term